# Como realizar um foreach no sqlserver?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

tudo bem?
Estou com uma dúvida que é a seguinte:

Possuo 3 tabelas no sqlserver: tbl_Pedidos, tbl_Itens_Pedido e tbl_Produtos com os seguintes campos respectivamente:

[image: tbl_Pedidos]

[image: tbl_Itens]

[image: tbl_Produtos]

Basicamente o sistema funciona assim: Cadastro um pedido, nesse pedido adiciono os itens e salvo normalmente. A cada inserção de item, eu atualizo o estoque do produto na tabela tbl_Produtos.

Na inserção, consigo atualizar o estoque normalmente a cada item através de um update simples, porém, como eu poderia atualizar o estoque de vários itens ao excluir um pedido inteiro que possui vários itens atrelados a ele?

Agradeço a ajuda.

Abraços.

Comment: Trigger poderia ser uma solução para insert , update ou delete.

Comment: Você pode definir delete cascade na tabela pedido. Isso faz que uma exclusão na tabela pedido também remova as linhas relacionadas nas outras tabelas.